# SQL SELECT string Greater than using count()

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to list groups that have more graduate than undergraduate student members. I feel I have the concept behind my idea, but making the query is a little more difficult then a simple translation. Below is my code, I currently am getting a missing right parenthesis error where COUNT(student.career = 'GRD'). Thanks.

```
SELECT studentgroup.name 
COUNT(student.career = 'GRD') - COUNT(student.career = 'UGRD') 
AS Gradnum FROM studentgroup 
INNER JOIN memberof ON studentgroup.GID = memberof.GroupID
INNER JOIN student ON memberof.StudentID = student.SID
WHERE Gradnum > 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT studentgroup.GID, max(studentgroup.name)
FROM studentgroup 
INNER JOIN memberof ON studentgroup.GID = memberof.GroupID
INNER JOIN student ON memberof.StudentID = student.SID
GROUP BY studentgroup.GID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN student.career = 'GRD' THEN 1 
                WHEN student.career = 'UGRD'THEN -1
                ELSE 0
            END) >0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT studentgroup.name 
SUM(CASE WHEN student.career = 'GRD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN student.career = 'UGRD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS Gradnum FROM studentgroup 
INNER JOIN memberof ON studentgroup.GID = memberof.GroupID
INNER JOIN student ON memberof.StudentID = student.SID
WHERE Gradnum > 1
GROUP BY studentgroup.name;
```

Comment: This gives the error FROM keyword not found where expected. I will try to mess with this a little bit and see if I can get it

Comment: It seems the FROM function does not like being called after the SUM

Answer (score 0):

I have used WITH As clause which is supported by most of DBMS like SQL Server, PostGresSQL except MySQL

```
With grpTbl As
(

SELECT studentgroup.name As StudentGroupName,
       SUM( CASE WHEN student.career = 'GRD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'TotalGraduate',
       SUM( CASE WHEN student.career = 'UGRD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'TotalUnderGraduate'

FROM studentgroup 
INNER JOIN memberof ON studentgroup.GID = memberof.GroupID
INNER JOIN student ON memberof.StudentID = student.SID

)


SELECT StudentGroupName
FROM grpTbl 
WHERE TotalGraduate > TotalUnderGraduate
```

For MySQL you can use Temporary table to store resultset from First query and filter out the GroupNames which have more Graduate than UnderGraduate in `WHERE` clause .
This method will work for other DBMS also difference being syntax of creating temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE grpTbl (
StudentGroupName varchar(255),
TotalGraduate INT,
TotalUnderGraduate INT
);


INSERT INTO grpTbl
SELECT studentgroup.name As StudentGroupName,
           SUM( CASE WHEN student.career = 'GRD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ,
           SUM( CASE WHEN student.career = 'UGRD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 

    FROM studentgroup 
    INNER JOIN memberof ON studentgroup.GID = memberof.GroupID
    INNER JOIN student ON memberof.StudentID = student.SID 


 SELECT StudentGroupName
    FROM grpTbl 
    WHERE TotalGraduate > TotalUnderGraduate


 DROP TABLE grpTbl
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
SELECT studentgroup.name
FROM studentgroup INNER JOIN memberof ON studentgroup.GID = memberof.GroupID
                  INNER JOIN student ON memberof.StudentID = student.SID
GROUP BY studentgroup.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN student.career = 'GRD' THEN student.career END) 
         > COUNT(CASE WHEN student.career = 'UGRD' THEN student.career END)
```

Comment: Well done. This is also another way to go about solving my problem!